# Copy and paste disabled in LyX 2.0

Tags: lyx, copy-paste

I try to copy and paste in a LyX document I am editing and it says that the command (paste) is disabled. This happens with anything, be it normal text, figures or formulae. I am working on a 64 bit PC with Windows 7 and using Lyx 2.0. I checked the document settings in short cuts and they are set. This is so frustrating.
Can anyone help me please?

Comment: This may be because `Ctrl+V` is bound to some other command. Can you paste by using the regular `Edit` menu?

Comment: I suppose that you have a write protected document. That happens for all example documents of the LyX documentation.

Comment: It's 2016 and this bug in LyX still isn't fixed. Not that copy&paste is an essential feature for a text processor \*sigh\*. Anyhow, restarting LyX makes the issue go away for a while, in my case.

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problem when I use LyX 2.0.2 on 64 bit PC with Windows 7. It happen sometimes, and can be resolved by restarting the LyX. I also use LyX on other OS, e.g., 32 bit Windows 7 and Ubuntu, and never encounter this problem there. Maybe this is a compatibility issue on the 64 bit Windows.

Comment: Just save everything, close it and open it again (restart as Shoreming mentioned). It'll work hopefully.

Comment: Had the same problem - restarting the computer solved it.

Comment: Problem still exists in LyX 2.0.6 (Win7 x64). Restarting LyX still solve the problem.

Comment: Problem still exists in LyX 2.2.0 (May 2016). Restarting LyX solved the problem for the first paste, but then the second thing I wanted to paste failed. Is there not a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

Same problem in LyX 2.1.4 on Windows 7.
I remapped `ctrl+v` to `paste 0`
and `ctrl+shift+v` to `paste`

The first allows me to paste within LyX keeping all the formatting etc.
The second gives me access to the clipboard. This seems to work well.
I'm not sure what causes this issue though.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your question won't be seen by many people here, so it would be best to repost it as a fresh question. [Follow-up questions](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2117) like this are more than welcome! Please use the "[Ask Question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)" link for your new question; there you can link to this question to provide the background.

Comment: Can you please explain to us how you did this remapping?

Comment: @user1271772: I'm a year late, but for future readers, go to Tools → Preferences → Editing → Shortcuts. This answer worked for me with LyX 2.1.4. (It has the bug, but for me restarting does work. I remapped Shift-Ins to `paste 0` so that I do not have to restart just to paste some LyX selection.)

Answer (score 0):

While I still do not know the culprit of this problem, I think I have found a workaround.

Even when `paste` is disabled, I found `paste recent` is still active, so I just binded ctrl+v to `paste 0` instead of `paste`. It seems to be working well so far.

-- Edited --

I spoke too early. It works within LyX, but `paste recent` does not capture texts copied outside of LyX.

Comment: Did you manage to fix it? I've also run into this problem http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/277997/paste-command-no-longer-working-in-lyx

Comment: Except my answer, unfortunately no. But in my case restarting LyX fixes the problem so it is not critical.