# Paste command no longer working in lyx

Tags: graphics, floats, lyx, windows, copy-paste

I have been using lyx for a while and everything was working smoothly. Recently, however, I tried deleting a float figure and inserting it at a different point in the document. Following [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43149/copy-and-paste-disabled-in-lyx-2-0) question I tried restarting lyx, the workstation, but the problem persists. I am using windows 7.

In this [thread](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=19635) it is mentioned that going **to Tools -> Editing, Shortcuts -> Cursor, Mouse and Editing Functions**

paste which is bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>. Apparently, I cannot change this binding. When clearing it the following message is shown:

[image: lyx copy paste]

Also, even when allocating <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to **selection-paste** the issue persists.

How can I fix this?

**Edit:**

I cannot even paste from the edit menu. The Paste tab is grayed out when an image has been copied. On the left corner of the editor the text "Command disabled" is shown. I have tried running lyx as administrator but the issue persists.

Comment: Perhaps it's not copying correctly...

Comment: Everything is grayed out and it worked before, when I tried copying images from another directory than the one in which the lyx file is located. Also, upon pasting the figure, a dialog box was shown in order to input the name of the new file to be stored in the directory containing the lyx file.

Comment: Did you update anything in terms of LyX?

Comment: No, at least not voluntarily(I know little about lyx's updating mechanisms).

Comment: I've found a solution by clicking the insert graphics tab while the cursor is in the figure.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an actual solution but more of a workaround. Instead of copying the image into its Float Figure container, I use the **Insert graphics** tab beneath the menu bar.

A more definite solution was to reinstall **lyx** (make sure you save the files you've been working on before; do not leave anything in the default working directories).